# Is there a way to selectively prune media providers from an admin interface in Sonata Media Bundle?

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-media-bundle

I am building a Page entity in a Sonata-based application, and I want inline editing screens for two types of media: YouTube videos and images.

I am using sonata_type_collection twice to create two inline forms, each of which calls out to a Media entity (from Sonata Media Bundle).

I want to be able to prune the list of available media providers in each case -- first to only allow YouTube as the provider, and second to only allow "Image" as the provider.

Is there a relatively simple way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

We ended up doing this by switching to sonata_type_model and providing a "provider" value in our second settings array. So the relevant code for uploading images ended up looking like this:

```
            ->add(
                'images',
                'sonata_type_model',
                array('expanded' => false, 'by_reference' => true, 'multiple' => true, 'required' => false),
                array('link_parameters' => array(
                    'context' => 'default',
                    'provider' => 'sonata.media.provider.image'))
            )
```